# allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' Error

Tags: asp.net

When I am deploying a project in Visual Studio 2008, I am getting the following error. What would cause this and how would I go about fixing it?

> It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Comment: This problem most commonly arises when you open the website in Visual Studio but accidentally open the parent of the root folder. For example, imagine that you have a website located at `C:\MyProjects\Website1`, where the` Website1` folder is the root of the website. When you open this website from Visual Studio you are asked to specify the website's root folder - it is imperative that choose the `Website1` folder.

Comment: If you accidentally select the `MyProjects` folder then the Web.config file in the Website1 folder is now in one of the website's subfolders. Because that Web.config file includes the <authentication> element, among other application-level settings, you'll receive the above error.The fix to this error (in most cases),Look up the documentation and add the required virtual directory. It should be a directory that has a web.config in it (not the root directory).or Removing a second web.config in a lower directory

Comment: http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/02/17/163375.aspx